# Изменить имена файлов в текущей директорий в нижний регистр. Как?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, find

Как переименовать файлы в нижний регистр ? Используя при этом find и awk

Пример (before):

```
./AaA 
./aAa 
./ ...
```

(after):

```
./aaa
./aaa
/ ...
```

Comment: Как минимум нужен mv и *sh 

Comment: Ну в целом нужна еще поддержка от ядра :D, пространство, управления процессами и т.д

Comment: UPD: изменен вопрос

Comment: `в текущей директорий` подразумевает файлы и в поддиректориях ?

Comment: Да. Все то, что входит в "./" или $PWD (pwd)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

так как в `простой` задаче по переименованию могут всплыть много проблем, постараемся заранее очертить их

1. Переименовать нужно файлы и **только файлы** в текущей и вложенных в неё директориях
2. Переименовывать нужно также и скрытые(те что начинаются на точку) файлы
3. Недопустить потерю файлов при переименовании когда конечное название будет одинаково, например: `FILE.txt` и `file.TXT` оба станут `file.txt` что приведёт к потере одного из них, в данном случае можно отметить файл с похожим названием дополнительным обозначением.

и так на основе вышесказанного, создадим полигон для тестирования учитывающие вышеупомянутые проблемы

```
$ rm -rf test;mkdir -p test/DIR; touch test/DIR/File" "1.txt; touch test/.File" "2.txt; touch test/{F,f}ile3.txt; tree -a test
test
├── DIR
│   └── File 1.txt
├── .File 2.txt
├── file3.txt
└── File3.txt

1 directory, 4 files
```

выполним команду для преобразования

```
$ find test -type f -execdir sh -c 'f="{}";mv --backup=numbered -v "$f" "${f,,}"' \;
mv: './file3.txt' и './file3.txt' - один и тот же файл
переименован './File3.txt' -> './file3.txt' (резервная копия: './file3.txt.~1~')
переименован './.File 2.txt' -> './.file 2.txt'
переименован './File 1.txt' -> './file 1.txt'
```

здесь `-execdir` выполнит команду только после перехода внутрь конечной папки, то есть это позволит нам избежать переименования поддиректорий.

по итогу получим

```
$ tree -a test
test
├── DIR
│   └── file 1.txt
├── .file 2.txt
├── file3.txt
└── file3.txt.~1~

1 directory, 4 files
```

здесь окончание `*.~1~` указывает на файл с дублирующим именем и он автоматом создаётся утилитой `mv` с помощью ключа `--backup`, при желании окончание можно переопределить под свои нужны с помощью ключа `--suffix`

**п.с.**

если обязательно для преобразования использовать `awk` то можно сделать так:

```
find test -type f -execdir sh -c "mv --backup=numbered -v \"{}\" \"\$(echo {} |awk '{print tolower(\$0)}')\"" \;
```

Comment: Я еще не читал более подробной информации. Какие книги порекомендуете по изучению GNU Linux ?

Comment: @badcast тема Linux довольно обширна, поэтому следует конкретизировать вопрос и лучше задать новым вопросом. Если же вас интересуют bash-скрипты то можете начать с этого [Bash-скрипты: начало](https://habrahabr.ru/company/ruvds/blog/325522/)

Answer (score 3):

Втекущей директории можно обойтись без find'а и awk'а, как-то так:

```
for f in *; { mv "$f" "${f,,}"; }
```

Comment: Удивительный пример. Работает!

Comment: даже если говорить тока о текущей директории, то при таком подходе могут всплыть куча подводных камней: 1) кроме файлов будет пытаться переименовать и директории. 2) файлы начинающиеся на точку будут проигнорированы. 3) возможна утеря файлов когда при переименовании они станут одинаковыми, например File.txt и file.TXT ---> file.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c "mv {} \$(echo {} | awk '{ print tolower(\$0) }')" \;
```